# Change variable if request are not received within some time from each other

Tags: python, flask

I have an ajax function that is posing data in intervals of 25 seconds to the class that you see bellow

```py
class StateInfo:
    flag = None 
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_data()
        info = json.loads(data)
```

Now what I wanna achieve is to set flag variable to 0 when there is no post request within 30 seconds of each other. I know that there is *.elapsed* but it returns time delta between request and response

Comment: You probably want a separate `timer` function that changes the flag after 30 seconds, with it's counter reset to 0 by a successful post request.

Comment: My naive approach would be to add a timestamp for the last post request made. Then simply check if the timestamp is older than 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already said in the comments, my naive approach would be to add a timestamp for the last post request made. Than simply check if the timestamp is older than 30 seconds.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

class StateInfo:
    flag = None 
    ts = None
    def post(self):
        ts = datetime.now()
        data = request.get_data()
        info = json.loads(data)
    
    def check_state(self):
        if ts < datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds = -30):
            flag = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    state_info = StateInfo()
    proc = Process(target=state_info.check_state())
    proc.start()
```

Note that I've added multiprocessing since you may have a second process, which needs to run at the same time. Although, you may have to repeat the process.

I hope this gives you a good idea, how you can achieve this. Also take a look at the suggestion from @match in the comments.